# UITableView row with image and label

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, label

I'm a new programmer and I'd like to start with a app where to show a table with an image and a label (dynamic). I can do it wist static table but now I'd like to know how to make it with swift. I'm following various tutorial but all say a easy table only array with text...

I'm sure your help will be useful many new as me...

Tutorial, code, are good accept...

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var smilefoto: UIImageView!

    var cellContent = ["Rob", "Kirsten", "Tommy", "Ralphie"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cellContent.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "tabella")

        cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        return cell       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'll have to do is create a custom UITableViewCell class, where you can create an imageview and label and anything else.

You should check this tutorial out:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG_AMY_gSDQ

And when you've done this, you'll have access of every object in that cell through that class:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProgramCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as YourCustomTableViewCell

    cell.yourCellImage = cellContent[indexPath.row].yourImage
    return cell

}
```

Also dont forget to link the tableView outlet from the storyboard to this viewController and set the DataSource to self (inherits from UITableViewDataSource)